# CSS Vertical middle input checkbox

Tags: css

I like to center a checkbox vertically inside a div. I've already tried to set `vertical-aligin: middle` with `display: inline-block`. This only workout while the checkbox iteself is `100%`. But than the full `100%` are selectable. Also tried to wrap the checkbox into another div with `vertical-aligin: middle` and `display: inline-block` without success.

```
<div style='height:100%;'>
    <input type='checkbox' style='display: inline-block; vertical-aligin: middle'/>
</div>
```

[image]

Right now my solution is :

```
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    top:  calc(50% - 6.5px);
    position: relative;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
<div style='height:300px; background: blue;'>
    <input type='checkbox' style='display: inline-block; position: relative; top: 48%;'/>
</div>
```

See here http://jsfiddle.net/j9c9V/